# sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccesorImpl. error - Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have an application developed in **Java** with database connection in **MySQL**. All the functions of the application work correctly but while I use the application (after 2-3 minutes in the application) a pop-up window opens and then the application goes into the background.

**What is this error due to?** I can't find any solution on Stackoverflow.

I use **JDK 8.0**. I run in the command console: `java -version`

```
C:\Users\omaza>java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

I use **Netbeans** IDE 8.2. My connector dabatase **MySQL** is: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar.`

**Code:**

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static Connection c = null;

/**
 * Conexión a BBDD.
 *
 * @param bbdd
 * @return
 */
public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
        return c;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace(), "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed! Se cerrará el programa...", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        n.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

View image:

[image]

Comment: More information is needed. Please update your question as follows: [1] Show the stack trace as text, not as an image. [2] Post your code that makes the connection (Method `conexion_a_BBDD()` in class `Conexiones`. [3] Specify the versions of all of the following: NetBeans, Java, MySQL and the database driver.

Comment: @skomisa I edited the question with as much information as possible.

Comment: OK. [1] Having the `Connection` variable `c` as `static` means every time you call your `conexion_a_BBDD()` method it will return an updated value for your only instance of `c`. That is probably not what you want, right? Try making `c` a local variable. [2] The requirement to call `Class.forName()` went away many years ago, though many JDBC examples incorrectly still blindly call it. See the [javadoc for **DriverManager**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) for more details. You can safely remove that line from your code.

Comment: @skomisa So how could I fix it in my code? Im lost.